# Manually trigger a drag event in snap.svg

Tags: snap.svg

How can I trigger a drag event manually in Snap.svg?

I have a drag event attached to an Element: Element.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragEnd), and would like to to trigger this event programmatically.

I have tried to trigger the event calling  Element.events[i].f(), where i represents the drag event, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Just trying to understand what you are trying to do...is it not possible to define your own snap drag handler (move,start,end funcs), which you could just call anyway as you require ? Or do you have to use .drag() ?

Comment: I have defined the functions, but it would be nice to be able to simply trigger the event without calling those manually. Seems like it works in Raphael http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059592/triggering-raphael-events-externally.

Comment: With `drag()` I'd expect it to put three separate objects in the `events` array, for dragMove, dragStart and dragEnd - which are you triggering? If that's not it, my guess would be that the namespacing changed since Raphael (or maybe the events are bound to the SVG not the JS object). Does `Element.events` exist, is it an array, is each item in the array an object, and does each object have a key `f()` which is a function? If so, does that function expect any arguments?

Comment: The events array exists, and there is a function f = function start(e, x, y), for the drag event. I get an error, "Cannot read property 'originalEvent' of undefined", which looking into the source code seems to originate from: function start(e, x, y) { (e.originalEvent || e).preventDefault(); ....

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I am looking for a way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any way within Snap to do this. I'm wondering if you could possibly fake an event and send it to fluff what you want (maybe jquery would be useful here).

I'm still not sure if this has any advantage over just calling the functions, as I assume emulating a drag can be quite fiddly, so I maybe missing the point with what you need, but it may give some idea!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFdj4/2/)

```
s = Snap(400, 620);

var r = s.rect(10,10,100,100);

r.click( function() { console.log('click') } );

r.drag( 
    function(x,y) { 
        console.log('move',x,y);
        this.transform('t' + x + "," + y );
    },

    function(x,y) { 
        console.log('start',x,y); 
    },

    function() { 
        console.log('end');
    }
  );


var e = new Event("mousedown" );
e.clientX = 34;
e.clientY = 35;
r.node.dispatchEvent( e ); //not sure if dispatch works on all browsers

var m = new Event("mousemove");
m.clientX = 40;
m.clientY = 40;
document.dispatchEvent( m );

var u = new Event("mouseup");
document.dispatchEvent( u );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out,

If you have defined dragStart, dragMove and dragEnd for your element you can do it like this. In my case .tool is a div outside the SVG area. When i then move my mouse over the svg area, the element follows the mouse around.

```
$(".tool").mousedown(function(event) {

Element.events[0].f(event, event.clientX, event.clientY);

});
```

Ofcourse you will need additional code to make it appear in the right position etc for you application. But this is how to trigger the drag event manually. :)