# How to trigger RaphaelJS Element.click() with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am having problems with triggering RaphaelJS's `Element.click()` with jquery. What I am trying to do is simulating with jquery that the Element.node was clicked and what I am expecting is that Raphael will delegate the click treatment to the previously defined `Element.click()` method.

In some circumstances I will need to trigger Raphael's Elements event handlers with code somehow using my `Element` instance.

In order to simplify my problem, I created a plnkr with just the code that does not work for me. So here is the example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AuSuq1RG6cWpqH2GEzcN?p=preview

What I expect of the code is that after `$(r.getById("square").node).trigger("click");` (I have also tried using `$(r.getById("square").node).click()`) is executed, `myRectangle.click(function() {...}` will be called and the heading on the result page will be changed to "The rectangle was clicked!". As you can see this does not happen. However clicking on the shape is working fine.

Does anyone know what do I miss in this small piece of code? How to make such manipulation work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After I worked around my initial problem so I can finish what I did start, now I found a helpful kinda-solution to the problem that might help others that come across my topic. What is written in the topic works and worth considering to be adopted as solution. It do look a bit hacky, but to be honest many things in JS do so. So here is the link, hope it can be helpful to someone someday :) - [Triggering Raphael events externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059592/triggering-raphael-events-externally)